# Import first 1000 records into sql server from a csv file

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import

I need to import a csv file into sql server table, but i only want to import the first 1000 records of the csv file.

This is my sql code,

```
USE MyDB
BULK INSERT MyTable
FROM 'C:\Users\jasons\Desktop\Documents\MyFile.csv'
WITH(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

What do i need to add or how can i change my code to only import the first 1000 records.

Comment: Use `lastrow`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
USE MyDB
BULK INSERT MyTable
FROM 'C:\Users\jasons\Desktop\Documents\MyFile.csv'
WITH(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
LASTROW = 1001
)
```