# Import only certain records based on a criteria into a SQL server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

In a previous question i asked how to import the first 1000 rows in sql server from a csv file. [Link to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25809676/import-first-1000-records-into-sql-server-from-a-csv-file)

Now i would like to know is it possible to import only certain records based on a certain criteria. For instance one column in my csv file is called Style. And i want to import all records where the style is equal to "ALE22".

Here is the code that works for me so far,

```
USE MyDB
BULK INSERT MyTable
FROM 'C:\Users\jasons\Desktop\Documents\MyFile.csv'
WITH(
FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
LASTROW = 1002
)
```

Comment: I don't think that can be done in 1 step. However, you can import it like you used to, and then use queries to do `SELECT INTO` whichever tables you want according to whichever filters you want.

Comment: @SchmitzIT has the right idea.  Bulk it into a temp table then select your values out into your production table.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this in one statement using the [openrowset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) bulk provider, but you will have to specify a format file to describe the column names and delimiters.

```
insert into x (
    v1, v2
) select top 1000
    *
from
    openrowset(bulk 'C:\Users\jasons\Desktop\Documents\MyFile.csv',
        formatfile = 'path_to_ff',
        firstrow = 2
    ) x
where
    x.Style = 'ALE22';
```

There are also text providers for `openrowset` that you could investigate.